# IOS Set UIViews on top of each other in storyboard

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard

How can I place UIViews on top of each other in the storyboard without nesting the UIView within each other? I want them to be subviews of the parent UIView, not subviews of each other. The default functionality always forces UIViews to go within each other, not on top of one another.

I am doing this because there will be background methods that control the visibility of such UIViews, which are connected via IBOutlet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way (the only way I know) is to drag the views from the `Objects` panel (the panel where all the vies and hierarchy is listed, marked with red) and create your desired hierarchy. But the annoying part of this process is, if you want to re position the views, you can't drag them because they will be nested again so you will have to move them using x, y, width, height values.

[image]